# Is it possible to create an Android widget that can input text

Tags: android, android-widget

I am looking at the official Android developer documentation for Android Widgets (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) and in that document it states that there is only a subset of views supported in widgets (AnalogClock,Button,Chronometer,ImageButton,ImageView,ProgressBar,TextView,ViewFlipper,ListView,GridView,StackView,AdapterViewFlipper) and clearly EditText is not one of them.

I was wondering if it is possible to capture text entered by the user in widgets.
The google now search bar is able to do so (when you click in it, it open the keyboard and shows a list of search history); is it because it is provided by the launcher thus it is not a regular widget?

Thanks

[image: before clicking the android search bar]
[image: after clicking the android search bar]

Comment: *The google now search bar is able to do so* no, it is not ... it opens new Activity with searchbar/editview

Comment: @Selvin i added a two images just to make sure that we are talking about the same google now search bar.
it is the unremovable search bar present in the stock launcher you get on nexus phones.

Comment: *unremovable search bar present **in the stock launcher*** ... it is an answer ... in other words, no you cannot use `EditText` in the widget

Comment: @Selvin that's what i thought, just wanted to be sure

Answer (score -1):

based on the official documentation that clearly states that EditText is not supported in Android Widgets and based on a previous comments from @Selvin, it does not seem possible to achieve something similar to the unremovable google now search bar present in the stock google launcher where user input is captured in an EditText in a Widget